# minimize $\log_a x+1$ subject to $0\leq a\leq x$

Tags: calculus

My book says "If $0\leq a \leq x$, then minimum value of $\log_a x+\log_x x$ is $2$."

But [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize%20%28log_%28a%29%20x%29%2b1%20%20subject%20to%200%3C=a%3C=x) says that it isn't!

Why is so?

Comment: Do you mean $\log_a(x)+\log_x(a)\ge2$? If not, then $\log_x(x)=1$ simplifies to $\log_a(x)\ge1$

Comment: And that too for $1<a\leq x$, right? @robjohn

Comment: It would appear so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discrepancy arises because you are allowing values of $a$ that are less than $1$. Then $\log_a x$ is *negative* for $x > 1$.

If that is really what the book said, then it was careless. It should have stipulated $1 < a \le x$.

Comment: Yes, and I also was thinking the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all in order for $\log_a x$ to make sense we need that $a>0$ and $a\ne 1$.

Case 1. $a>1$, then $\log a >0$, and hence $\frac{1}{\log a}\ge\frac{1}{\log x}$, and thus
$$
\log_a x+\log_x x=\frac{\log x}{\log a}+1\ge \frac{\log x}{\log x}+1=2,
$$
since $0<a\le x$ implies that $\log a\le \log x$.

Then minimum is attained for $x=a$. The maximum is $\infty$. Take for example $a=x^{1/n}$, then the left-hand side in $n+1$.

Case 2. $a<1$. Then $\log_a x=\log_{1/a}(1/x)<1$, as $1/x\le 1/a$, and hence 
$$
\log_a x+\log_x x\le 2,
$$
and the maximum is achieved for $a=x$.

Comment: How did you get $\frac{\log x}{\log a}\leq \frac{\log x}{\log x}$ ? or $\log a\le \log x$ for that matter?

Comment: If $\log a\le \log x$, then how $\frac{\log x}{\log a}\leq \frac{\log x}{\log x}$ is derived?